# Peer authentication failed for user "db_user"

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to set-up automatic backup for postgres db on a local headless server on Debian. I have a script:

```
#!/bin/bash
export PGPASSFILE='/home/mtn/.pgpass'
pg_dumpall -U db_user --verbose 2>/var/log/postgresql/pgdump.log | gzip > /mnt/bulk-data/db_backup/db_bak.gz
```

Have a `.pgpass` file:

```
-rw-------  1 mtn  mtn     47 Nov 13 10:14 .pgpass
```

with:

```
*:*:*:postgres:guest
*:*:*:db_user:guest
```

And a `sudo crontab -e` job:

```
20 0 * * * /home/mtn/backup.sh >/dev/null 2>&1
```

`pg_hba`:

```
local   all             postgres                                peer
```

When i try to run it i get:

```
pg_dumpall: error: could not connect to database "template1": FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "db_user"
```

Where's the mistake?

PS Everything works if i change the script to run as root `sudo -u postgres pg_dumpall`.

**UPDATE**:
What worked for me in the end is adding this line to `pg_ident.conf`:

```
omicron           root                    postgres
```

Then to `pg_hba.conf` before everything else:

```
local   all      all                 ident map=omicron
```

And changing script to run `pg_dumpall` as user `postgres` (only because `db_user` didn't have all necessary privilegies to `dumpall`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the absence of a user map via pg_ident.conf, only a linux user named "db_user" is allowed to log in as the database user "db_user".  That is what peer authentication means.  Your `.pgpass` doesn't matter, as peer authentication doesn't use passwords.

The one line from pg_hba you show also doesn't matter, because "postgres" != "db_user" so that line doesn't match.  But clearly you have other lines as well which you haven't shown us.  If you look in the server's log file you should find more details about the error, and which line of pg_hba was used.

There are lots of solutions.  You could change your linux username to match the postgres username, or change the postgres username to match the linux username, or use pg_ident.conf to map between them, or change your pg_hba (the correct line of it!) to use md5 rather than peer.